# How to Send Jpg Image from one activity to another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

Hope You Are Fine
Well am stuck in a little bit of problem...I have a main activity in which i am using custom listview(showing movie_poster,movie_name,movie_rating)...and i want that if i click on a row a new activity should be open and jpeg image (movie_poster)in that row should be show in other activity...i tried a lot of things but could not find a solution..

```
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent=new 

           Intent(MainActivity.this,Description_Activity.class);

            int index= (int)parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);

            String description=movie_descriptions[index];

            intent.putExtra("title",movie_titles[index]);
            intent.putExtra("rating",movie_ratings[index]);
            intent.putExtra("desc", description);


            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: you can simple pass the path(image URL or local path) of the image in intent extra and retrieve in second activity and load that image.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on row Send Image path to activity using intent.

```
 intent.putExtra("title",movie_titles[index]);
 intent.putExtra("rating",movie_ratings[index]);
 intent.putExtra("desc", description);
 intent.putExtra("resourseInt", R.drawable.image);    

 startActivity(intent);
```

On Second activity

```
int res = extras.getInt("resourseInt"); 
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.something); 
view.setImageResourse(res);
```

Comment: Are you getting Poster image path from server or not?

Comment: when i click on a row..i get movie_poster id..so now from this id ..how can i send image?

Comment: i alredy accepted...but my rank is 1 ..so that it is saying that you can not accept it unless you have 15 rank.reputation....cause i am new in stackoverflow

Comment: how can i find you find you furthur...? is there any frind system r something like that in stack overflow..?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send Image it self you have to send Image URL, Resource ID, or path from SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the image coming from? If its a url pass the url or its its coming from local disk, then pass the disk path:

```
intent.putExtra("image",<your_url_or_path>);
```

And then use this url or path in your second activity to show the image wherever you want to show it.

Comment: look  i have a array of int stroing images id..and images are in drawble

           int[] movie_poster_resource={R.drawable.madmax,R.drawable.antman,R.drawable.chappie,
            R.drawable.themartian,R.drawable.therevenant,R.drawable.uncle,R.drawable.creed,
            R.drawable.insideout,R.drawable.jurrasicworld,R.drawable.starwars
    };


from this images are shown in my custom ListView

Comment: Then pass the drawable ids to the second activity. And then use this drawable id to show the image in that activity.